# Does Kotlin's version of Java's for each have the same limitations?

Tags: java, kotlin, foreach

I'm currently learning Kotlin coming from Java. In Java, doing

```
for(String s:stringList){
   if(condition == true) stringList.remove(s);
}
```

doesn't work, as you can only read data with for each. Does this also apply to Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same restriction as in Java - when you're iterating over a collection, you're limited to modifying it through the `Iterator`'s [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) method

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next(). **The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method**.

Kotlin has [its own equivalent](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/iterators.html#mutable-iterators) (bearing in mind Kotlin uses the concept of mutable and immutable lists, so you can only do this with a `MutableList`)

The problem with the `foreach` / enhanced `for` structure is it doesn't expose the `Iterator` you need to call `remove()` on, and you're not allowed to call `remove()` on the collection itself. And Kotlin's the same - so your options are basically

- use `for`/`forEach` (but you can't modify the collection)
- call the collection's `iterator()` method and iterate over it yourself (now you can call `remove()` on it, with the restrictions I quoted)
- avoid mutability and produce a new collection

The last one is what you're encouraged to do in Kotlin - instead of modifying a collection, try to use immutable ones and transform them into new collections instead:

`stringList.filterNot { condition }`

If you get familiar with all the [collection functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) (yeah, there are a *lot* of them) you'll get an idea of the ways you can transform A to B, and the convenience functions that are there to help you do it (e.g. [`filterTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-to.html) which lets you provide a `MutableList` to populate with the items you want to keep).

If you do want to modify mutable collections in place though, it's possible but you have to manage it yourself, because it's inherently dangerous and the system can't guarantee you're doing it safely.

Comment: There's a more functional way of mutating a list in-place: [removeAll(predicate: (T) -> Boolean)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html). But yes, most of the time, it's better to use `filter()` or similar to create a new list.

Comment: Oh yeah, that one's actually perfect for what the OP's trying to do! Although I'm assuming it creates another Collection in the background so it can do the usual ``removeAll(elements)`` call - so if mutating a list in-place is about memory efficiency or something, that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the current implementation of the predicate version of `removeAll()` is very efficient: for `RandomAccess` lists such as `ArrayList`, it does a single scan through the list, copying items in-place as it goes. (If not `RandomAccess`, it falls back to calling `remove()` on the iterator instead.) Of course, that's only an implementation detail, and not guaranteed; but future versions are unlikely to reduce performance.

Comment: Oh neat, thanks for checking! And not being lazy like me... but it does go to show, it's a good idea to make use of the library functions where you can - there are a lot of people working to make those neat and efficient implementations, so you don't need to worry about doing it yourself. So if there's a function that does what you want, you should probably use it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you rewrite this code in Kotlin, you'll get the same concurrent modification problem:

```kotlin
for (s in stringList) {
   if(condition == true) stringList.remove(s)
}
```

To avoid this problem, you can obtain a mutable iterator from a mutable list and use it to remove elements on the go. But unlike Java, you don't have to iterate it manually with `hasNext()`/`next()` calls — you can use the same `for` operator for iterating it:

```kotlin
val iterator = stringList.iterator()
for (s in iterator) {
   if (condition == true) iterator.remove()
}
```